# How to refer to employees of other businesses in a business presentation?

Tags: single-word-requests

In a mock school activity, I'm presenting to 'shareholders', 'business mentors' (teachors) and members of other companies (fellow students).

I am unsure how to address those from other companies. My current sentence is:

> Good morning, shareholders, mentors and ___

What is a suitable term?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you almost had it when you posed the question:

> Good morning, shareholders, mentors and **fellow employees**.

There is no reason to specify that you are only talking to employees of *other* companies. I assume that some in the audience are employees of your own company too. But even if not, you are addressing *all* employees. (The use of *fellow* means that you are am employee also.

---

If you don't like *employees* specifically, then:

> Good morning, shareholders, mentors and [**colleagues**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/colleague).

This will remove any appearance of "inequality."

> an associate or coworker typically in a profession or in a civil or ecclesiastical office and often of similar rank or state : a fellow worker or professional

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, as the teams are small, about a third of the audience are in high-up managerial positions, so I was afraid 'employees' may even be slightly insulting.

Comment: fellow entreprenneurs?

Comment: @GeorgeTian Understood. I have updated my answer with an alternative.